# Showing that set $X$ is countable or finite if there is an injective mapping $f:X \to N$

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

I am trying to prove that if there is an injective mapping $f:X\to \mathbb{N}$, then $X$ is finite or countable.

My proof goes like this:

---

Suppose that $X$ is infinite and uncountable.

Since $X$ is uncountable, there is no bijection for $X\to \mathbb{N}$, nor for $\mathbb{N} \to X$.

We know that since $f$ is injective, then in order to follow the definition that $X$ is uncountable, $f$ must not be surjective.

*However, since $X$ is uncountable and infinite, it is clear that $|X| >> |\mathbb{N}|$.*

*Since $f$ is injective, each and every fibre of $X$ must map to some infinitely countable element $n \in \mathbb{N}$ uniquely.*

*This forces $f$ to be surjective. Which causes a contradiction because $f$ is now a bijection while there cannot be one for $X \to \mathbb{N}$.*

Therefore, $X$ must be finite or countable if $f:X \to \mathbb{N}$ is injective.

---

I am sceptical about this proof because of the parts in italics. I feel that I have made some incorrect assumptions/statements.

To solidify my conceptual knowledge of the problem, could someone help me?

Comment: Did you mean:  "Therefore, $X$ must be finite or *countable* if $f$ is injective"?

Comment: Indeed "infinitely countable element $n \in \Bbb N$" makes no sense. A natural number is not infinitely countable because it is not a set. Anyway, you cannot prove that $f$ is surjective, because for example the map $n \mapsto (n+1)$ is not surjective, yet still injective.

Comment: You can't have finite and uncountable simultaneously, so "uncountable and infinite" = "uncountable". What is your definition for $|A|\ge|B|$?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner That's a typo. I need to fix that

Comment: @Crostul but is the set of all natural numbers infinitely countable?

Comment: @NelliKuukeri the "absolute value" of a set is the number of elements in that set.

Comment: That is obvious, but what does "the cardinality of $A$ is greater or equal to the cardinality of $B$" mean for you?

Comment: Well, unfortunately, I am very new to this topic. I don't know how to explain what you just asked me, but I did say that I am sceptical with my proof and I did want some help to correct it.

Comment: Is your definition simply: $|A|\ge|B|$ if there is a surjection $A\to B$ or an injection $B\to A$?

Comment: I would say if there is a surjection $A \to B$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105979/discussion-between-paydayzcool-and-nelli-kuukeri).

Comment: "ust map to some infinitely countable element n"  There's no such thing as an infinite element.  Nor a countable or uncountable element.  Elements are single elements.  The terms "infinite", "countable", "uncountable" and "finite" (in terms of cardinality) refer to *sets*; not individual elements.  An element is a single value.  And when we say it is "finite" (and *all* elements are finite) we are using the word in a very different sense.  We mean the element has a value that is bounded within some range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy approach

Since $f:X\rightarrow \mathbb N$ is injective hence $\lvert X\rvert \le \lvert\mathbb N\rvert$ which proves that cardinality of $X$ cannot be greater than that of $\mathbb N$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but why is it that you can say $|X| \leq |\mathbb{N}|$ if $f$ is injective?

Comment: If $f:A\rightarrow B$ is injective then number of elements in $A$ cannot be greater than number of elements in $B$. For e.g. if $A=${$1,2,3$} and $B=${$x,y$} then you cannot give a $f:A\rightarrow B$ which is injective.